# Mask image out from parent div

Tags: html, css, mask, clipping

I want to clip a `png` image off a `div`. How can I do that?

This is the closest I could get to what I'm looking for, using `mix-blend-mode`, but it will not help me if the div's background color isn't `#000` or `#fff`:

[image: black header with title clipped off]

Here's a simple snippet to work with:

```css
html, body {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/m0TaGXH.png");
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0.5em 1%;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  width: 98%;
  background: #1c1b20;
}
header > img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xZaujwq.png">
</header>
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at `mask-image`? (not supported much) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

Comment: @KevinJantzer `mask-image` gives me [the opposite effect](http://i.imgur.com/CepXw6C.png). Also, I have no idea how to stop it from repeating.